# Удобный лог под Node.js

Tags: node.js, логирование, сервер

Друзья, делаю сервер под Node.js. Подскажите, как лучше всего логировать?
В php логировал так:

```
    function e($message)
    {
        print(date("H:i:s",(time()+TIME_ZONE)).' '.$message);
    }

    $this->e("The player was disconnect...\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так сделал с миллисекундами...

```
function e(text)
{
    var date = new Date();
    console.log('['+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+':'+date.getSeconds()+':'+date.getMilliseconds()+'] '+text);
}
```